# Calling a function in an Ionic 2 component

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am working on an app that has numerous forms. Some of these forms are very very large (50+ fields). The user is allowed to fill one or more form, and when this is submitted, the generated JSON is send to a PHP backend, which converts it to CSV.

The backend PHP service is unaware of the structure, it simply converts each JSON element to a column/value.

**The problem**

Currently, if the user completes Form 1 and Form 4, the generated CSV looks something like this:

```
FORM 1,  ,  ,  FORM 3
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col1,Col2,Col3
Val1,Val2,Val3,Val1,Val2,Val3
```

I need to change this, so regardless of whether FORM 2 is filled, its columns are printed in the CSV with empty values. This way, the CSV output will have a consistent structure.

**Possible approaches**

One way I can solve this is simply define an object for FORM 2, and send it along with Form 1 and Form 3 with empty values:

```
    type    Form2 = {
        columns : {
            col1 : string,
            col2 : string,
            col3 : string
        }
    };

    let form2Object = {
        columns : {
            col1 : '',
            col2 : '',
            col3 : ''
        }
    } as Form2;
```

However, doing this for the many forms I am working with, each with numerous columns, will literally take me days.

The second way I am hoping to solve this by is simply to create a function that returns Form 2's values like so:

```
function returnFormTwo() {
    return this.formTwo.value
}
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to call a function in the Form 2 component in Ionic 2?

I am trying something like this:

```
import { FormTwoPage } from '../pages/form-two/form-two';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public appGlobal: AppGlobal, public formTwo: FormTwoPage) {}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    let formTwoObj = this.formTwo.returnFormTwo();
}
```

How should I go about doing this?

Thanks.

**Update:** this is how FormTwoPage looks:

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'page-form-two',
        templateUrl: 'form-two.html'
    })

    export class FormTwoPage {
        formTwo: FormGroup;

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public toastCtrl: ToastController, 
            public appGlobal: AppGlobal, public dataService: FormData, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

            this.formTwo = formBuilder.group({
                col1: [''],
                col2: [''],
                col3: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(40)])]
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the form part of the html template of whichever component you are calling from?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry, I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child)

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild(FormTwoPage) 
formPage:FormTwoPage;

ionViewDidLoad() {
   let formTwoObj = this.formPage.returnFormTwo();
}
```

Make sure `returnFormTwo()` is `public`.

**Update**
You *dont* have inject to the page in the constructor.FormTwoPage is not a provider to set in the constructor.

Comment: I get this error:

Runtime Error
Can't resolve all parameters for FormTwoPage: (NavController, NavParams, FormBuilder, ToastController, AppGlobal, ?, ModalController).

Any idea?

Comment: is it solved? if not can you add FormTwoPage component to question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant with your update about @Injectable?

Shall I add @injectable somewhere?

Comment: you have a FormTwoPage entry in the constructor in the question.. It is not a provider so it shouldnt be injected in the constructor. Providers are defined with `@Injectable` instead of `@Component`

Comment: Yes, but FormTwoPage is a component, with a template and all. Check the updated question for FormTwoPage.

Comment: So it is not recognizing FormData provider? are you importing FormPageTwo component in the service? You may have a circular dependancy. check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914044/ionic-2-custom-provider-causing-cant-resolve-all-parameters/42921451#42921451) for the same error

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the original post. This is ho: import { FormTwoPage } from '../pages/form-two/form-two'. 

The service is under /src/providers/ and the pages are under /src/ too.

Comment: use forwardref to inject formdata like the linked answer

Comment: Linked answer? I tried adding @Injectable to the FormTwoPage but the same error persisted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914044/ionic-2-custom-provider-causing-cant-resolve-all-parameters/42921451#42921451 and dont put `@injectable` to formtwopage

Comment: Looks like that fixed the error, but now I get Typescript Error
Declaration expected. @ViewChild(FormTwoPage) 
formPage:FormTwoPage;

Comment: did you import viewchild?