# How to call an Ionic function defined in service.ts from app.html

Tags: ionic-framework

I have defined a function in services/auth.service.ts which I used for different pages' functionality

For example if I wanted to use it in homepage

1) import { AuthService } from '../../app/services/auth.service';

2) in the constructor I add

```
public authService: AuthService
```

3) Whenever I want to call a function defined in auth.service.ts, I call the function using `this.authService.funcname()`.

**Functions are called from header of the page**.

Now, I wanted to add the sidemenu and need to call the function from there.

1) I added the sidemenu content in the app.html file so need to call the function from there.

If I call the function, it throws the following error:

> TypeError: co.launchSignout is not a function

Content of app.html

```
<ion-menu side="left" [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>        
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>


            <ion-item (click)="launchSignout()"  *ngIf="signoutbutton" menuClose>
                Logout
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

launchSignout() is defined in auth.service.ts, now I don't know how call the function.

### Update

As suggested, I added

1) import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service'; in app.component.ts

2) added provider  providers: [ AuthService ] in app.component.ts

3) added public authService: AuthService in the constructor in app.component.ts

4) called the function in app.html

```
<ion-item (click)="authService.logout()"  *ngIf="signoutbutton" menuClose>
            Logout
        </ion-item>
```

But It throws the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you
>   have a circular dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel'
>   index.ts files

Comment: Just call ``authService.launchSignout()``, as long as you have injected ``public authService: AuthService`` in your ``app.component.ts``'s constructor.

Comment: @Matt while adding, it underlines authService and displays this message: [ts] Cannot find name 'authService'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.authService'?

Comment: Matt meant in the html..not the component.ts

Comment: @suraj  it throws someother error bro please see the edit..

Comment: @Matt it throws someother error bro please see the edit..

Comment: have you imported the page in the provider?

Comment: @suraj There is no separate page for signout bro.. I have pages for login , signup and one Homepage. Homepage is imported in auth.service.ts bro

Comment: that is the problem. you are importing homepage in authservice and authservice in homepage causing circular dependancy.. rethink your design

Comment: or try https://stackoverflow.com/a/42921451/4826457

Comment: @suraj but it was working fine bro.. when I was calling the function defined in auth.service.ts from pages' html

Comment: Keep references to UI components out of your (core) services. This is bad design, as you will have a hard time testing your services. It might make sense in specific situations, but mostly it just causes trouble.